# how to specify range in Avro schema?

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I am using Avro schema but I'm not sure how to specify the range for a particular record.

```
{
   "name": "longitude",
   "type": "int"
}
```

Let's say this "longitude" can take values only from 0 to 100. How do I mention the range of the longitude in Avro schema?

Comment: You can create a custom logical type with your validation for your avro schema. Avro doesnt have any existing checks for range

Comment: is there any other way to take care of the range in avro schema?